How can I play mp3 files from Python3 on Raspberry Pi 4 (running Ubuntu server 22.04, 64 bit)?
I'd like to do this:
playsound("/dev/shm/tts-speech.mp3")

I used to use playsound in Ubuntu 20.04.  It doesn't work in Ubuntu 22.04, so I used playsound from preferredsoundplayer.  That works fine on my pc, but doesn't on my rpi4.
I get strange output, and no sound:
>>> import preferredsoundplayer as ps
>>> ps.playsound("/dev/shm/tts-speech.mp3")
('\n', '')

What is the simplest way to play sound files on rpi4 from python (or fix preferredsoundplayer)?

After hours of struggling with this, I found the answer minutes after posting the question!
It is easy to make preferredsoundplayer work.  preferredsoundplayer uses ffmpeg as one of its output players, and ffmpeg requires two environment variables to be set.
export SDL_AUDIODRIVER="alsa"
export AUDIODEV="default:1"

The AUDIODEV will depend on the device through which you want to play sounds.  In my case that is the Respeaker Mic Array 2.0.
For reasons I cannot explain, the syntax hw:1,0 will not work for audio output via the Respeaker (even though aplay -l shows this to be the device designation).  I found the name default:1 through alsamixer and that does work.
